# How to update database table in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to update table in database when contacts on phonebook are updated. I tried to update my table when my application is started. Here is my code

```
package com.contactsdemo;

import Dat.DataDemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DataDemo aa = new DataDemo(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        aa.onUpgrade(db,1,2);
        if(c.getCount()>0){
            while (c.moveToNext()){
//              String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                aa.insertData(name);
            }
                aa.close();

        }
    }


}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String value1, String value2, String value3) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_VALUE1, value1);
        args.put(KEY_VALUE2, value2);
        args.put(KEY_VALUE3, value3);
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

Hope it will useful :D